# Get user input when window focused, input from file focussed or not

Tags: python, tkinter, parallel-processing

This is sort of a multi-threading question but not really. I have a Python **Tkinter** *Toplevel* window (Python 2.7 & 3.5 tested):

[image: wman remove new windows.png]

The second button is defined as:

```
    btn2 = tk.Button(button_frame, text='Remove new', \
                     command=self.remove)
    btn2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
```

Which when the button is pressed calls this function:

```
def remove(self):
    ''' Remove windows on monitor now that weren't there at start '''
    new_windows = []
    new_windows_cnt = 0
(... SNIP out boring stuff ...)
```

The above code works when window has focus and user clicks button. Now I'm creating this Ubuntu Unity Keyboard Custom Shortcut:

[image: Ubuntu custom keyboard shortcut.png]

<sub>Note: Shortcut doesn't appear to work but that's not a biggie</sub>

---

## Now the parallel processing part of the question

Create a function that continuously runs when *Toplevel* window doesn't have focus:

```
def parallel_processing(self)
    while (not_toplevel_destroyed):
        try:
            f = open("/tmp/w")
            self.remove()
        except IOError:
            pass         # TODO: Test if IOError is even, else delete this and above
        finally:
            f.delete()

        time.sleep(.1)
```

Note: It is OK if this new function also runs when *Toplevel* window has focus in which case it will be a 1/10th second delayed accelerator key.

How do I call this new function after `btn2` is packed?

How do I kill this new function when *Toplevel* is destroyed by button 1 which contains:

```
btn = tk.Button(button_frame, text='Close', \
                command=self.toplevel.destroy)
btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
```

---

## Solved!!!

The accepted answer below works but there were some errors in my concept draft. Here is the final code:

```
import os
import time
(... SNIP ...)

        button_frame = tk.Frame(self.toplevel)
        button_frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        btn = tk.Button(button_frame, text='Close', \
                        command=self.close_toplevel)
        btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        btn2 = tk.Button(button_frame, text='Remove new', \
                         command=self.remove)
        btn2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.toplevel_active = True
        self.parallel_processing()

    def close_toplevel(self):
        self.toplevel_active = False
        time.sleep(0.2)
        self.toplevel.destroy()

    def parallel_processing(self):
        if os.path.exists("/tmp/w"):
            os.remove("/tmp/w")
            self.remove()

        if self.toplevel_active:
            root.after(100, self.parallel_processing) 

    def remove(self):
        ''' Remove windows on monitor now that weren't there at start '''
        new_windows = []
        new_windows_cnt = 0
(... SNIP ...)
```

Here is the test proof:

```
$ echo 1 > /tmp/w

$ ll /tmp/w
ls: cannot access '/tmp/w': No such file or directory
```

The file doesn't exist because the python program is working. The `parallel_processing(self)` function appears to add less than 1% CPU load.

Comment: run it in separated thread or uses `root.after(milliseconds, function_name)` instead of `while` and `sleep` to repeate it periodically. As button1 - assing function which (1) stops/kills function and (2) runs `self.toplevel.destroy()`

Comment: @furas Sorry I'm still learning. Can you post the few new new lines of code embedded within the code I posted? In case the `self` didn't give itself away the code is all wrapped up inside a single class. I will immediately upvote and be happy to accept the answer after testing. If you would be so kind, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand problem.

You can use `root.after` instead of `while` and `sleep` and it will not block `root.mainloop()`

```
def parallel_processing(self)
    try:
        f = open("/tmp/w")
        self.remove()
    except IOError:
        pass         # TODO: Test if IOError is even, else delete this and above
    finally:
        f.delete()

    if self.not_toplevel_destroyed:
        root.after(100, self.parallel_processing) 

btn2 = tk.Button(button_frame, text='Remove new', command=self.remove)
btn2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

self.not_toplevel_destroyed = True
self.parallel_processing()
```

---

You can assign function which will set `not_toplevel_destroyed = False` to stop function and wait few milliseconds to make sure, and then it will destroy window.

```
def close_app(self)
    self.not_toplevel_destroyed = False
    time.sleep(0.2)
    self.toplevel.destroy()

btn = tk.Button(button_frame, text='Close', command=self.close_app)
btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know if I'll get this incorporated tonight. One thought though instead of `self.not_toplevel_destroyed = False` (granted my initial draft) to avoid double negatives `self.toplevel.active = True` (or at least that philosophy if not literally for this line of code) will be my coding technique.

Comment: There was an error in my TODO comment: `IOError is even` should have read `IOError is even necessary`. Doesn't effect the code of course but comments are important too :)

Comment: I just got started incorporating the code and there is a problem having `time.sleep(0.2)` in the program. It causes the popup window which is a grandparent above toplevel to be transparent with options invisible. I had to comment this line out to make popup window visible. Also I used `close_toplevel` as the function name instead of `close_app` which is misleading. FYI the app is root, then ResizingCanvas(), then mycanvas, then popup menu, then this *Toplevel* in question. Ironically, my app has a function called `restart` which actually needs to sleep .2 after root.destroy before restarting.

Comment: There were also errors in the `parallel_processing(self)` function in my concept draft. I've got it all working now and I've accepted your answer. Forget about what I said about  `time.sleep(.2)` it works OK. Thank you very much and I'll post the revised code later.